# Importing *.dae file with multiple texture to papervision 3D

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, augmented-reality

usually when you export a 3D object with *.dae format there's a folder that comes with the file, the folder contains the texture of the object, does anybody know how to add a *.dae file and its texture to our project ?

Answer (score 1):

You should place textures into folder with *.dae and load your object and textures like this:

```
    var bm:BitmapFileMaterial = new BitmapFileMaterial('PATH_TO_TEXTURE', true);
    var mat:MaterialsList = new MaterialsList();
    mat.addMaterial(bm2, 'MATERIAL_NAME');
    mat.addMaterial(bm3, 'ANOTHER_MATERIAL_NAME');

    var obj:DAE = new DAE();
    obj.useOwnContainer = true;
    obj.load('PATH_TO_DAE', mat);
```

Also, materials should be correctly linked in *.dae. Something like this:

```
    ...
      <library_images>
        <image id="TEXTURE_NAME-image" name="TEXTURE_NAME">
          <init_from>2/TEXTURE_NAME.png</init_from>
        </image>
      </library_images>
      <library_materials>
        <material id="TEXTURE_NAME" name="TEXTURE_NAME">
          <instance_effect url="#TEXTURE_NAME-fx"/>
        </material>
      </library_materials>
    ...
      <library_visual_scenes>
        <visual_scene id="RootNode" name="RootNode">
          <node id="TEXTURE_NAME_tp3_Mesh01" name="TEXTURE_NAME_tp3_Mesh01">
            <matrix sid="matrix">1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000</matrix>
            <instance_geometry url="#TEXTURE_NAME_tp3_Mesh01-lib">
              <bind_material>
                <technique_common>
                  <instance_material symbol="MATERIAL_NAME" target="#MATERIAL_NAME"/>
                </technique_common>
              </bind_material>
            </instance_geometry>
          </node>
        </visual_scene>
     </library_visual_scenes>
```

...

Comment: thank you vladimir, i'll report soon as i try it on my project